# Loading images faster on a website in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to import photos from a local file on my computer to my HTML file. I have managed to do this but I need to speed up the time it takes to load in on the page, 2.4mins. My idea was to load a smaller file size of the image, 200px by 200px and then load the full-sized image in the background. The problem that I am encountering is that I am not able to integrate my code of loading the images from a local file with the lazy loading code. can anyone help?

```js
const $spans = $("span");
const {
  length
} = $spans;
$spans.each(function(i) {
  $(this).append("<img src='Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-" + (length - i) + ".JPG' />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Images"></span>
```

Comment: 2.4mins is a massive amount of time. Roughly, how many images are you trying to load?

Comment: Your title also conflicts with the body of the question. It would appear that 'loading in smaller images first' isn't what you're trying to solve here, but to simply make image loading faster. Please add more detail.

Answer (score 2):

I'd look into using [**intersection observerAPI**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver) for lazy loading images, there's an excellent [Google Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/lazy-loading-guidance/images-and-video/#inline_images) on this whole subject.

A basic example of this is:

Alter your `<img>` tags to add:

- `data-src`
- `data-srcset`

**These point to the image to load once the element is being looked at in the "viewport".**

**Example**:

```
<img class="lazy" src="placeholder.jpg" data-src="lazy-img-1x.jpg" data-srcset="lazy-img-1x.jpg 1x">
```

Then in a `<script>` tag or wherever you run your page's code just have a function that listens for the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var lazyImages = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img.lazy"));

  if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
    let lazyImageObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
      entries.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          let lazyImage = entry.target;
          lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src;
          lazyImage.srcset = lazyImage.dataset.srcset;
          lazyImage.classList.remove("lazy");
          lazyImageObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
        }
      });
    });

    lazyImages.forEach(function(lazyImage) {
      lazyImageObserver.observe(lazyImage);
    });
  } else {
    // Possibly fall back to a more compatible method here
  }
});
```

[Here's a CodePen](https://codepen.io/malchata/pen/YeMyrQ) from the guide with a better example.

Comment: Hi, I saw a similar version to this when I was looking for a way to lazy load but my problem was trying to get lazy loading to work with the code I have already got.

Comment: I believe you could take the function from my answer place that in your jQuery file instead. I’d also pre-populate the HTML with image tags from the example as well.

Comment: Then the problem that I am encountering is that I am not able to dynamically load all my images from a directory.

Comment: I see. We’d probably need you to give a fuller example in the question. You are appending the images to ‘this’ but are you 100% sure of what ‘this’ is at runtime? Perhaps try adding a ‘debugger’ statement in the loop to see what’s happening. Also, I’d select the ‘<span>’ by adding a class then selecting it using a class for best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Before you upload images for use on a website, you should **optimize** them first to prevent slow load time/your current issue.

As your images are seemingly stored in a local folder, I would suggest to first, make a back-up of the folder containing the images [to an external hard drive or another area of your hard drive].

Then, visit an image compression site (such as [tinypng](https://tinypng.com/),  - I use this but there are others, e.g [CompressJpeg](https://compressjpeg.com/)) Compressing images will greatly reduce the file size but the images will appear the same. You can upload multiple images at a time, and download bundles of compressed images as a zip. Ensure that when you extract the images, that they are named as you would like (and that they don't have a '1' at the end [as usually added, to indicate that the file is a copy/2nd version])

When you run your code using the smaller images, you should find that your processing time is reduced substantially.

Hope this helps

A sidenote - Both the afore-mentioned websites handle both jpgs and png formats - the website names can be misleading! :)